# Jquery hover state - text change

Tags: jquery

Hey Fellow Developers,

1)I have a hover state that shows text on rollovers. It works fine until i duplicate the code.

Once images are duplicated it shows all rollover text rather than one at a time.

2) ALso can anybody make the following work;
when clicked on "follow" and "chart" button, I want the hover text to change from "Follow" to "Following" and when clicked back, changes back to "follow" hover.

Please see live demo below 
http://jsfiddle.net/w3N2f/13/

```
<script>

    $('.chart-interest-btn').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });

    $('.follow-interest-btn').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });



    $(".follow-interest-btn").hover(function(){
        $(".interests-follow-popup").show();
    }, function(){
        $(".interests-follow-popup").hide();
    })


    $(".chart-interest-btn").hover(function(){
        $(".interests-chart-popup").show();
    }, function(){
        $(".interests-chart-popup").hide();
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$(".follow-interest-btn").hover(function(){
    $(this).siblings(".interests-follow-popup").toggle();
});


$(".chart-interest-btn").hover(function(){
     $(this).siblings(".interests-chart-popup").toggle(); //Select only the siblings with the class
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aHJMx/)**

You need to make your selector specific rather than mentioning the generic classname which can be present anywhere.

Similary for the point 2 you can do:

```
$('.follow-interest-btn').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $this.siblings('.interests-follow-popup').text(function(){ //Select only the siblings with the class and set the text
        return $this.is('.active') ? 'Following' : 'Follow'; // check if the element is active based on it swap the text.
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DhTwS/)**

- [siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)
- [.text(fn)](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-functionindex--text)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $('.interests-follow-popup').text("Following")
} else{
    $('.interests-follow-popup').text("Follow")
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/w3N2f/14/)

Comment: could you create jsfiddle example?>

Comment: @PaulO'Brien Click on demo to get to the jsfiddle example